# Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: backbone.js

I'm pretty new to backbone and I'm reading, following its example to create a todo list. I can't figure out why this piece of code does not work:

```
 var Todo= Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:       {
        title       :   "",
        completed   :   false
    },

    initialize:     function(){
            console.log("model initialized");
            this.on("change", function(){
                console.log("values for this model have changed.");
            });
    }        
});

var todo1= new Todo();
```

the libraries I've included are jquery, underscore and backbone. What's wrong with this? Why ".on" is not available? Thanks

Comment: Which versions of those libraries are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on` was only included in Backbone 0.9.0. You need to update it.